# SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, ssl, heroku

We have been working on an express site for a past few months. We deployed our site to Google Cloud engine and it was up and running without any issues till yesterday. We were unable to login or open some pages. When we checked our Google logs we found the following error.

```
{"textPayload":"","insertId":"605cd74e000cae81bbb16449","resource":{"type":"gae_app","labels":{"project_id":"kiddopia","version_id":"20210325t235730","module_id":"kiddopia-web-app-staging","zone":"us16"}},"timestamp":"2021-03-25T18:32:46.831105Z","labels":{"clone_id":"00c61b117c58a7870c65d75e8fb684a… 
 at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16) { 
errno: 'EPROTO', 
code: 'EPROTO', 
syscall: 'write' 
}
```

So we tried changing node versions, redeploying the site and also testing it on some other platforms like heroku. We are still facing the same issue on heroku as well.

We didn't change any code before the issue started and it was working fine till yesterday evening. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a self - signed certificate?
That's generally the cause for this error

Comment: No. We are using google app engines certificate. And this wasn't an issue for last few months. It just started on 25th March

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with GCP. It got resolved automatically in 2 days.